# How to center the Text in the middle of the Container? Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, containers

i want to center my texts in the middle of my containers but they only center them in top middle of the containers.
Here is my code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Homepage extends StatefulWidget {
  const Homepage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _HomepageState createState() => _HomepageState();
}

class _HomepageState extends State<Homepage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Homepage'),
          backgroundColor: Colors.green,
        ),
        body: SafeArea(
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(75, 100, 75, 100),
                height: 100,
                width: 300,
                color: Colors.green,

                child: const Text('BLE & Data'),
              ),
              //const SizedBox(height: 10),
              Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(75, 25, 75, 100),
                height: 100,
                width: 300,
                color: Colors.green,
                child: const Text('Statistiken',
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,),
              ),
              const SizedBox(height: 10),
                Container(
                  //padding: EdgeInsets.all(50),
                  margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(75, 25, 75, 100),
                height: 100,
                width: 300,
                color: Colors.green,
                child: const Text('Personal Data',
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ));
  }
}
```

And that´s my output: [Demo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qFxbR.jpg)

I would be very thankful if anyone can solve my problem

Comment: Wrap your text with Center Widget

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to wrap your text widget with the center widget.

```
Center(child:Text("")),
```

Add This Code:-

```
class Homepage extends StatefulWidget {
  const Homepage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _HomepageState createState() => _HomepageState();
}

class _HomepageState extends State<Homepage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Homepage'),
          backgroundColor: Colors.green,
        ),
        body: SafeArea(
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(75, 100, 75, 100),
                  height: 100,
                  width: 300,
                  color: Colors.green,
                  child: const Center(child: Text('BLE & Data')),
                ),
                //const SizedBox(height: 10),
                Container(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(75, 25, 75, 100),
                  height: 100,
                  width: 300,
                  color: Colors.green,
                  child: const Center(
                    child: Text(
                      'Statistiken',
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                const SizedBox(height: 10),
                Container(
                  //padding: EdgeInsets.all(50),
                  margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(75, 25, 75, 100),
                  height: 100,
                  width: 300,
                  color: Colors.green,
                  child: const Center(
                    child: Text(
                      'Personal Data',
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap whatever you want centered in a [Center](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Center-class.html) widget:

For example:

```
Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(75, 100, 75, 100),
            height: 100,
            width: 300,
            color: Colors.green,

            child: Center( child: const Text('BLE & Data') ),
          ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `alignment : Alignment.center` of `container()` widget.

```
class Homepage extends StatefulWidget {
  const Homepage({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _HomepageState createState() => _HomepageState();
}

class _HomepageState extends State<Homepage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Homepage'),
          backgroundColor: Colors.green,
        ),
        body: SafeArea(
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(75, 100, 75, 100),
                  height: 100,
                  width: 300,
                  color: Colors.green,
                  child: const Text('BLE & Data'),
                ),
                //const SizedBox(height: 10),
                Container(
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(75, 25, 75, 100),
                  height: 100,
                  width: 300,
                  color: Colors.green,
                  child: const Text(
                    'Statistiken',
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  ),
                ),
                const SizedBox(height: 10),
                Container(
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  //padding: EdgeInsets.all(50),
                  margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(75, 25, 75, 100),
                  height: 100,
                  width: 300,
                  color: Colors.green,
                  child: const Text(
                    'Personal Data',
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ));
  }
}
```

[image]